# Loading additional stylesheets after initial html and main css file is loaded and rendered

Tags: css, lazy-loading

**MOTIVATION:**

I am trying to accomplish something where i use the following scss setup:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
  @media only screen and (min-width: $i*53px) {
    .middle:not(:nth-child(#{$i})) {
      width: calc((100vw - 2*#{$X} ) / (#{$i} - 1));
      > div {
        left: calc(50% - 0.5*#{$P});
      }
    }
    .middle:nth-child(1) {
      width: calc((50vw + (#{$i} - 2)*#{$X} ) / (#{$i} - 1));
      > div {
        left: calc(#{$X} - 0.5*#{$P});
        right: auto;
      }
    }
    .middle:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      width: calc((50vw + (#{$i} - 2)*#{$X} ) / (#{$i} - 1));
      > div {
        left: auto;
        right: calc(#{$X} - 0.5*#{$P});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(You are probably thinking that a flexbox/grid/table approach would seem better, but that simply does not work the way i want)

The main issue here is that the actual css file becomes very large. What i would like is to split this loop up into smaller sections, and load the additional css stylesheets after initial load and render.

**THE PROCESS I IMAGINE**

1. initial get request, the user should be able to cache all static files.
2. Load the main html file and the css file with the first part of the loop (say 20 iterations)
3. Wait for the browser to fully load and render the two files from server or local chache.
4. after the two files are rendered, start loading the next css file with the next 20 iterations from server or cache
5. after this file has loaded and been applied to the dom/rendered, start step 4 again with the next file. Stop after x files has been loaded.

What would be the best approach for such a setup?

Comment: I have found this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Performance/CSS,

Looking to find some possible solutions there.

Comment: It seems that this can be accomplished by using the media attribute on the css link tag to make the css non render blocking. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Performance/CSS#optimizing_for_render_blocking